# What should I do to compare those decimals with a BC -l?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

This is what I have so far in a shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

n1=3.5
n2=3.6
n3=3.7
n=3
promedio=`echo "($n1 + $n2 + $n3)" / 3 | bc -l`
echo Las notas del estudiante son: $n1 - $n2 - $n3 y el promedio es $promedio

if [ `echo $promedio -lt 3.0 | bc -l` ]; then
echo Studen is low
elif [ `echo $promedio -gt 3.0 | bc -l`] -o [ `echo $promedio -lt 3.5 | bc`]; then
echo Student is ok
elif [ $promedio -gt 3.5 && -lt 4.0 ]; then
echo Student is good
elif [ $promedio -gt 4.0 ]; then
echo Student is excellent

fi
```

Can you see what I'm trying to do? I got confused in the bc -l part and I'm trying to figure out how to do this exactly. What should I do in this situation? I'm trying to compare the result of `$promedio` greater than 3.0 and echo something, like the others.
First I had some errors like:

```
./estudiante.sh: line 12: [: 3.60000000000000000000: integer expression expected
./estudiante.sh: line 14: [: missing `]'
./estudiante.sh: line 16: [: 3.60000000000000000000: integer expression expected
```

and now:

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
Student is ok
```

Am I doing this ok? Or I need to do something else? Thank you!

Comment: You are missing spaces in some conditions like `...bc -l`]` should be `bc -l` ]`

Comment: The aritmethic operators like `-lt` don't work with decimals.

Comment: @guillermochamorro thanks for answering I deleted that little space in the first one, but the same problem in the terminal. Oh I see, what should I use instead of -lt and -gt if those one doesn't work with decimals? I'm really confused...

Comment: For `bc` you need the `<>` operators: `$(echo $promedio < 3.0 | bc -l)` (it's recommended you use `$()` surrounding commands than bacticks). But there are other problems with your code.

Comment: @guillermochamorro ah I see. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bc` uses `>` and `<` for numeric comparisons.

Also keep in mind that `bc` outputs the truth value:

```bsh
$ echo "2 > 1" | bc
1
$ echo "2 > 3" | bc
0
```

You have to do this:

```bsh
if [[ $(echo "$promedio < 3.0" | bc -l) == "1" ]]; then
    echo Studen is low
elif [[ $(echo "3.0 <= $promedio && $promedio < 3.5" | bc) == "1" ]]; then
    ...
```

Or you can use bash's arithmetic conditional, which handles "0" as "false" and non-zero as "true":

```bsh
if (( $(echo "$promedio < 3.0" | bc -l) )); then
    echo Studen is low
elif (( $(echo "3.0 <= $promedio && $promedio < 3.5" | bc) )); then
    ...
```

Comment: thank you so much! I see what I was doing wrong now with the -lt and -gt in decimals, I didn't know that, but now I know! Thanks, now I can continue!